# A function to check if a node is present in an xml file

Tags: xquery

I have a function that takes a node and returns true or false if the node is part of a group of nodes for example I  have this xml document:

```
    <person>
     <name> Joseph </name>
     <child> Mary </child>
     <mother> Janet </mother>
     <father> Fred </father>
    </person>
```

I have a function that should return true if the node passed in is either a father or name it should return true but I'm getting this error 
Axis step child::element cannot be used here: the context item is absent

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here

```
    declare function local:findNode($node as element())
    {
      for $s in person/(name,father)
      return
        if($s = $node)
         then true()
        else false()
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function, the expression `person/(name,father)` has no context. Update the function to accept the person element as a variable and use that as the context: `$person/(name, father)`.

Also, because this iterates over the `(name, father)` sequence with a `for`, the function will return multiple boolean variables - one for `name` and one for `father`. If you compare the sequence of values to the passed in value, that will return true if *any* value of the sequence evaluates to true, and false if they are all false, which it sounds like what you want:

```
declare function local:findNode(
  $node as element(),
  $person as element(person)
) as xs:boolean
{
  $person/((name, father)=$node)
}; 

let $person :=
<person>
 <name> Joseph </name>
 <child> Mary </child>
 <mother> Janet </mother>
 <father> Fred </father>
</person>
let $node := <name> Rick </name>
return local:findNode($node, $person)
```